# IntelliJ not showing lines that begin with '#' in test output

Tags: intellij-idea, commaide

I'm using InelliJ for the first time. Just to get familiar with it, I have a test that dumps the output of a markdown file to STDOUT. While it does work, all lines beginning with the '#' sign don't show up, as if it thinks it should be treated as a comment. Weird.

When I run the test outside of IntelliJ from the command line, I get the expected results.

Is there some kind of setting that an control the output of tests so these lines will show?

From the picture below, you can see '#hello world' is not showing while 'hello world' is. I'm using the Comma CP IDE for Raku, the latest version.

[image]

Comment: Could not reproduce that: https://i.imgur.com/NqfE8ya.png
Please sahre more details.

Comment: I have a good idea why it's happening, just not sure how to fix it. I'm using raku which I assume used TAP. In TAP, diagnostics being with the `#` sign. Diagnostics can be ignored by the testing program.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov I added a screenshot and more details about which version of Comma IDE I'm using. It's base on IntelliJ.

Comment: If I turn off the plan directive in the test file, I get full output. Of course, the test fails.